Why is a memory address turning negative after only adding offsets to it?
Hello I am experimenting with editing values inside games via python. I'm running into an issue where the script is trying to read a negative memory address however I am not subtracting anywhere in the script. I am new to this but I assume negative memory addresses are not a thing?
Here is my code.
from pymem import *
from pymem.process import *

Mem = Pymem("KingdomsAndCastles.exe")
BaseAddress = module_from_name(Mem.process_handle, "mono-2.0-bdwgc.dll").lpBaseOfDll
Offsets = [0x5C, 0x0, 0xD0, 0x10, 0x558, 0xB0]

def GetPointerAddress(Base, Offsets):
    Address = Mem.read_int(Base)

    for Index, Offset in enumerate(Offsets):
        if Index != len(Offsets)-1:
            Address = Mem.read_int(Address + Offset)

    Address = Address + Offsets[-1]

    return Address

PointerAddress = GetPointerAddress(BaseAddress + 0x00499440, Offsets)

Mem.write_int(PointerAddress, 1000)

I am getting an error on line 13 Address = Mem.read_int(Address + Offset) error pymem.exception.MemoryReadError: Could not read memory at: -1349507980, length: 4 - GetLastError: 998
Also I am using cheat engine to get my data

Also I did notice that if I run Mem.write_int(0x26320688590, 1000) (the last address you can see in the pointer) it does properly update the value in game.

Pymem.read_int returns a signed 4-byte integer. That can wrap negative if you perform addition beyond its maximum value of 2^31. In languages like C and C++, that's also undefined behavior. I don't know whether that's also the case in Python. Anyway, assuming your program is actually 32-bit, then you should use read_uint. If the program is 64-bit, then use read_ulonglong.

@paddy god bless your soul
